# elasticsearch showing only 1 docs.count on data migration using logstash

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to move data from S3 (.csv file's data) to elastic search cluster using logstash using custom templete.
But it only shows docs.count=1 and rest of the records as docs.deleted when i check using following query in Kibana:-

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

My first question is :-

1. why only one record [the last one] is transmitted and others are transmitted as deleted ?

Now when I query this index using below query in Kibana :-

```
GET /my_file_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I get only one record with comma separated data in `"message" :` field, So the second question is :-

2. How can I get the data with column names just like in csv as I have specified all column mappings in my template file which is fed into logstash ?

I tried giving columns field in logstash csv filter also but no luck.

```
 columns => ["col1", "col2",...]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT-1: below is my logstash.conf file:-

```
input {
 s3{
     access_key_id => "xxx"
     secret_access_key => "xxxx"
     region => "eu-xxx-1"
     bucket => "xxxx"
     prefix => "abc/stocks_03-jul-2018.csv"
   }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["AAA","BBB","CCC"]
  }
}
output {
    amazon_es {
        index => "my_r_index"
        document_type => "my_r_index"
        hosts => "vpc-totemdev-xxxx.eu-xxx-1.es.amazonaws.com"
        region => "eu-xxxx-1"
        aws_access_key_id => 'xxxxx'
        aws_secret_access_key => 'xxxxxx+xxxxx'
        document_id => "%{id}"
        template => "templates/template_2.json"
        template_name => "my_r_index"
 }
}
```

Note: 
Version of logstash : 6.3.1
Version of elasticsearch : 6.2

EDIT:-2 Adding template_2.json file along with sample csv header :-

### 1. Mapping file :-

```
{ 
    "template" : "my_r_index", 
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 50,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
         },
         "index.codec" : "best_compression",
         "index.refresh_interval" : "60s"
      },
    "mappings" : { 
        "_default_" : { 
            "_all" : { "enabled" : false },
       "properties" : { 
        "SECURITY" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "SERVICEID" : {
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "MEMBERID" : {
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "VALUEDATE" : {
            "type" : "date"
        },
        "COUNTRY" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "CURRENCY" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "ABC" : {
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "PQR" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "KKK" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "EXPIRYDATE" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "SOMEID" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "DDD" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "EEE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "FFF" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "GGG" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "LLL" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "MMM" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "NNN" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "OOO" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "PPP" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "QQQ" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RRR" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "SSS" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "TTT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "UUU" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "VVV" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "WWW" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "XXX" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "YYY" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "ZZZ" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "KNOCKORWARD" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RANGEATSSPUT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "STDATMESSPUT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CONSENSUPUT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CLIENTLESSPUT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "KNOCKOUESSPUT" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RANGACTOR" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "STDDACTOR" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CONSCTOR" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CLIENTOR" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "KNOCKOACTOR" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RANGEPRICE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "STANDARCE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "NUMBERICE" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CONSECE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CLIECE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "KNOCICE" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "SKEWICE" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "WILDISED" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "WILDATUS" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RRF" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "SRF" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CNRF" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CTRF" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RANADDLE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "STANDANSTRADDLE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CONSLE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CLIDLE" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "KNOCKOADDLE" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "RANGEFM" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "SMIUM" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CONIUM" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CLIEEMIUM" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "KNOREMIUM" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "COT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "CLIEEDSPOT" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "index" : "false"
        },
        "IME" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "KKE" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
        }
        } 
    }
    }     
}
```

2. **My excel content as:-**

   Header    :   Actual header is quite lengthy as have lot many columns, please consider other column names similar to below in continuation.

   ```
     SECURITY | SERVICEID  | MEMBERID | VALUEDATE...
   ```

   First row :  Again column values as below some columns has blank values , I have mentioned above real template file (in mapping file above) which has all column values.

   KKK-LMN   2   1815    6/25/2018
   PPL-ORL   2   1815    6/25/2018
   SLB-ORD   2   1815    6/25/2018

**3. Kibana query output**
Query :

```
GET /my_r_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Outout:

```
{
        "_index": "my_r_index",
        "_type": "my_r_index",
        "_id": "IjjIZWUBduulDsi0vYot",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "@version": "1",
          "message": "XXX-XXX-XXX-USD,2,3190,2018-07-03,UNITED STATES,USD,300,60,Put,2042-12-19,,,,.009108041,q,,,,.269171754,q,,,,,.024127966,q,,,,68.414017367,q,,,,.298398645,q,,,,.502677959,q,,,,,0.040880692400344164,q,,,,,,,159.361792143,,,,.631296636,q,,,,.154877384,q,,42.93,N,Y,\n",
          "@timestamp": "2018-08-23T07:56:06.515Z"
        }
      },
```

...Other similar records as above.

**EDIT-3:**
Sample output after using autodetect_column_names => true :-

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "indr",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "hAF1aWUBS_wbCH7ZG4tW",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "2": "2",
          "1815": "1815",
          "message": """
PPL-ORD-XNYS-USD,2,1815,6/25/2018,UNITED STATES

""",
          "SLB-ORD-XNYS-USD": "PPL-ORD-XNYS-USD",
          "6/25/2018": "6/25/2018",
          "@timestamp": "2018-08-24T01:03:26.436Z",
          "UNITED STATES": "UNITED STATES",
          "@version": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "indr",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "kP11aWUBctDorPcGHICS",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "2": "2",
          "1815": "1815",
          "message": """
SLBUSD,2,1815,4/22/2018,UNITEDSTATES

""",
          "SLB-ORD-XNYS-USD": "SLBUSD",
          "6/25/2018": "4/22/2018",
          "@timestamp": "2018-08-24T01:03:26.436Z",
          "UNITED STATES": "UNITEDSTATES",
          "@version": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "indr",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "j_11aWUBctDorPcGHICS",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "2": "SERVICE",
          "1815": "CLIENT",
          "message": """
UNDERLYING,SERVICE,CLIENT,VALUATIONDATE,COUNTRY

""",
          "SLB-ORD-XNYS-USD": "UNDERLYING",
          "6/25/2018": "VALUATIONDATE",
          "@timestamp": "2018-08-24T01:03:26.411Z",
          "UNITED STATES": "COUNTRY",
          "@version": "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your single document has an id of `%{id}`, right? The problem is that in your CSV you are not extracting a column whose name is `id`and that's what you're using in `document_id => "%{id}"` hence all rows are getting deleted excepted the last one.

Comment: Can you show the real headers and a sample line of your CSV ?

Comment: You are correct, I had to remove the document_id => "%{id} which got copied from sample logstash.conf file ,  as I did not have any id column in csv header.

Comment: @Val  but, I still get data in "message" : "<csv row data>" from not like in separate column field values. It should ideally show values with different column names in kibana output right ? I also have defined mappings for all columns in template_2.json file.

Comment: Feel free to share as much info as possible, i.e. your template, the top 2-3 lines for your CSV file, etc

Comment: {
    "template" : "my_r_index",
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 50,
            "number_of_replicas" : 1
         },
      },
    "mappings" : {
        "_default_" : {
            "_all" : { "enabled" : false },
       "properties" : {
                "AAA" : {
                        "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "BBB" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                }      }
    }
        }
}
My excel content as:-
AAA  BBB
code   2

Comment: Please update your question, it's more legible

Comment: Another problem is that your index template matches an index called `my_r_index` but the name you give in your output is `deepakindex` which will not match your template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178605/discussion-between-deepak-s-and-val).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty certain your single document has an id of `%{id}`. The first problem comes from the fact that in your CSV file, you are not extracting a column whose name is `id` and that's what you're using in `document_id => "%{id}"` hence all rows are getting indexed with the id `%{id}` and each indexation deletes the previous. At the end, you have a single document which has been indexed as many times as the rows in your CSV.

Regarding the second issue, you need to fix the filter section like below:

```
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      autodetect_column_names => true
  }
  date {
    match => [ "VALUATIONDATE", "M/dd/yyyy" ]
  }
}
```

Also you need to fix your index template like this (I've only added the `format` setting in the `VALUATIONDATE` field:

```
{
  "order": 0,
  "template": "helloindex",
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "codec": "best_compression",
      "refresh_interval": "60s",
      "number_of_shards": "10",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "UNDERLYING": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "SERVICE": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "CLIENT": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "VALUATIONDATE": {
          "type": "date",
          "format": "MM/dd/yyyy"
        },
        "COUNTRY": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {}
}
```

Comment: actually it is a csv file  so I am using ","  as separator . in my question I have ust used | to separate header column names . sorry for confusion.

Comment: Please show exactly your two first lines as they appear in the file and format that using a code snippet

Comment: I've updated my answer, the pipeline works on my end with your sample data.

Comment: It is just that I am getting column values not from header for record 2 it pics from header, then for record 3 it pics values from record 2 as header and so on. Due to some bug in logstash whiich is due to parallel worker threads on same file and each starting reading picking from different record locations. The solution was to give --pipeline.workers as 1 so trying that, but somehow it stopped transferring data to index. checking again

Comment: Now I increased --pipeline.workers to 10 and it transferred data but again the column headers mismatched. I have attached a sample output with the question to have a look.